# beginUpdates / endUpdates hangs when > 2000 rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableView with 170,000+ rows and noticed that calling

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

will cause my CPU usage to be 100% and freeze my app.

To troubleshoot this problem, I reduced my entire tableView to the simplest one possible and noticed that when I change the numberOfRows to more than 2000+, the app freezes longer and longer on beginUpdates / endUpdates.

I thought maybe this was due to autoLayout, so I deleted all my constraints and set my heightAtRow to a constant 40.0, but it didn't fix the problem.

My question is if the rows are being reused, why does beginUpdates / endUpdates (mind you, I'm not changing anything between those calls, I'm just calling it to test) take so long to process 170,000 rows?

My cellForRow method is blank, and my storyboard only has the contentView for the cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProductDescriptionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductDescriptionTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it take so long to process that number or rows?

Comment: Yes, I believe it had to do with tableViewRowHeight calculation. The trick was to set an estimated row height so that the tableView can load, and then the heights would be calculated once the user started scrolling.